# php session_start execute when condition not match

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
session_save_path('/home/path/to/session/');
if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'test'))
{
    echo 'a';
}else{
    session_start();
}
```

This script create a session file while the if is true( the file name is test.php)?

Comment: You shouldn't put too much into sessions. Their purpose is to keep a small amount of insensitive data during internal location changes. Maybe you want to add data to other scripts/users later then you'd have to rewrite your logic again.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'test'))
```

into

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'test') === false)
```

or

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'test') !== false)
```

depending on your needs (hard to say from your code). Otherwise if `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` starts with `test` strpos function returns 0 which is considered as false in statement you should replace. To compare exact value and type you need to use `===`or `!==` operators

Comment: What happen is : the output is a , which means the if condition is true, and the session file is still created(session_start() is in the else section). when I replace strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'test') with  some other expression, or simply a '1',everything works well...

Comment: What exactly do you want achieve? Please explain it in details